# Is every dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm not sure if this is true, but if it is, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded, there is some $M\in\Bbb R$ such that $\|\mathbf x\|\le M$ for every $\mathbf x\in A$. Let $\mathbf v=(2M,0,\ldots,0)$. Then the ball $B(\mathbf v,M)$ does not intersect $A$.

Another proof: let $\mathbf e_1=(1,0\ldots,0)$. The ball $B(n\mathbf e_1,1)$ intersects $A$ for every natural $n$. Then $A$ is not bounded.